# postgresql search timestamp between dates with java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have with my partner a project for uni. one question is to select timestamps between dates.
I.E

`select * from table where timestamp >= 2020-10-10 and 2020-10-15.`

it works fine, but the timestamp doesnt show the 2020-10-15 day.

is there a good way to include the full day?

Comment: `select * from table where timestamp BETWEEN 2020-10-10 AND 2020-10-15.`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'full day'?

Comment: Note that `2020-10-15` would mean the time `00:00,000` so start of the day. You might want to use `2020-10-16` instead, add the time or convert the timestamps to dates, e.g. via `DATE(timestamp)`.

Comment: @Thomas thank you Thomas, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

First cast "timestamp" to `date` and then as @ArvindKumarAvinash said in his answer use inclusive `between`. This would include the full day.

```sql
SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _timestamp::date BETWEEN '2020-10-10' AND '2020-10-15';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE expression is wrong. When using `>=` and `<` you need to repeat the column name.

When comparing a `timestamp`  value (date **and** time) with a date value (without time), it's usually better to use `<` on the upper bound and compare with the "next" day, otherwise you wouldn't catch the values after `00:00:00`

```
select * 
from table 
where "timestamp" >= date '2020-10-10' 
  and "timestamp" < date '2020-10-15' + 1;
```

This is more efficient than casting `"timestamp"` to a date, as this expression can make use of an index on the `"timestamp"` column.